# posts_id of POSTS using GRAPH API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting posts on Users wall using Graph API.

How can I get the `Post ID` for these posts which I am doing so i can later
read or write comments on these posts?

Comment: Have you looked at the response?

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { link:  body,picture:PICTURE,name:'NAME',description:'DESCRIPTION',caption:'CAPTION',message:'MESSAGE'      }, function(response) {
 if (!response || response.error) {
  alert('Error occured');
} else {
 alert('Post ID: ' + response.id); //response.id is the post ID of the post published.
}
```

Sorry you are using graph api...My bad.
When the post is published you get the id in the response.
Check it. it should be in JSON fomat. "id:POST_ID" Something like that.